# How would I use bitwise operations to easily generate points in a cuboid?

Tags: c++, c, geometry, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have a cuboid with a center (`Vec3` or `float[3]`), width, height and depth. I want to assign a `Vec3[8]` array with the 8 vertices in a cuboid. I want it to be done in a nested for loop. In order to do it in a for loop I have to use the following formula:

```
points[n][dim] = cub.center[dim] (+ or -) dimensions[dim]/2;
//n is nth point, dim is the dimension of the point: 0 = x, 1 = y, 2 = z
//dimensions is {cub.width, cub.height, cub.depth}
```

For example if a cuboid is facing towards you and you want the x coordinate of the point in the back top left, it's the equivalent of:

```
points[0][0] = cub.center[0] - dimensions[0]/2;
```

but for back top right:

```
points[1][0] = cub.center[0] + dimensions[0]/2;
```

We can abstract this as:

```
int coefficient = (cond)?1:-1;
points[n][dim] = cub.center[dim] + coefficient * dimensions[dim] / 2;
```

If I make sure to order the points like this:

```
[0] = back top left
[1] = back top right
[2] = back bottom left
[3] = back bottom right
[4] = front top left
[5] = front top right
[6] = front bottom left
[7] = front bottom right
```

The coefficients of these are:

```
[0] = back top left      | - - -
[1] = back top right     | - - +
[2] = back bottom left   | - + -
[3] = back bottom right  | - + +
[4] = front top left     | + - -
[5] = front top right    | + - +
[6] = front bottom left  | + + -
[7] = front bottom right | + + +
```

This resembles binary, but I'm not familiar with bitwise operators and need help figuring out what `cond` is using n and dim.
My guess is:
`cond = dim'th binary digit of n == 1`
Any help would be appreciated as well as any easier ways of assigning the 8 points using a for loop.

Comment: So if I understand your question right, you have a truth table consisting of 3 bits and a single result. Appropriate matching binary operation is `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int coefficient = (n & ( 1 << dim)) ? 1:-1;
```

Assuming `<0,n,7>`  and `<0,dim,2>`